# Run a VBA script from an Event in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, odbc

I created an MS Access Database that consists of about 25 ODBC Database Links that are connected to one table on each of these databases. Each of these tables have the same structure, but different data. Then, I Union these tables with a query so that I can have all the data available in one view.

The problem that I'm having, is that every time I try to use the query from a reporting software (Crystal Reports), I have to manually connect to all 25 databases, which is very tedious.

I made a VBA connection Script that connects to each of the databases using its log information, however I don't know how to trigger this code from an event like Opening the Query or something like that.

Any ideas?

Comment: VBA only runs from an office application.

Comment: @ckuhn203 I understand. I'm talking about MS Access, which is part of Office.

Comment: so you have your mdb file with its ODBC connections to the 25 or so tables and your union query available in the same mdb file, as a 'sql-specific' union query ... is that right?

Comment: An Access query does not expose events which you can use to run VBA code.  Could you drive this from Access instead --- set up your connections and then call the Crystal Report?

Comment: @PhilippeGrondier Correct.

Comment: @HansUp I'm not 100% sure what you mean. I can't store username and passwords, and if I can I'm not sure how to; hence the reason I have to do it programmatically. When I run the vba code, that I already have, it logs into each one, but I'm trying to have it run the code on an event, specifically, on opening the query, so that on Crystal reports you do not have to log into 25 different databases before running the report.

Comment: Are you running Crystal Reports from within Visual Studios?  Are you building the report as part of a .NET application?

Comment: Right, we are probably not on the same page ... likely because I don't know Crystal Reports.  But the first point remains true ... Access does not expose query events that you can associate with VBA procedures.

Comment: @Blackhawk Not in Visual Studio. Crystal Reports 9 Application. That's the reporting software we use.

Comment: @HansUp Crystal Reports is just a reporting software. I used Access to join my ODBC tables and I'm calling the view(query) from the MS Access File.

Comment: @HansUp What you you think about an [AutoExec macro](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/create-a-macro-that-runs-when-you-open-a-database-HA010336239.aspx)?  Do you think that the Crystal Reports Access Add-In might trigger it?

Comment: @Blackhawk An AutoExec macro fires when the db is opened in an Access application session.  But if Crystal Reports only reads data from the db file without starting an Access application session, the AutoExec will not run.  I don't know how Crystal interacts with an Access db file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to relink the tables in your Access Database on the "External Data" tab.
When you get to the "Link Tables" dialog, make sure you click the "Save Password" option before clicking "OK". This will store the password information in the linked table definition. The linked tables you just created will be brought in with a "TableName1" name.

During this next step, DO NO OPEN YOUR QUERIES. They will break if you don't complete this step first.

Delete your original linked tables from the Access database. Then, remove the "1" from your new linked table names. This will effectively replace your original links with ones that have persistent password information.

I'm not 100% positive, but I believe this will fix your issue. I don't believe there is any way to trigger vba or any kind of macro when running your query from Crystal Reports, so your ODBC credentials need to be stored in the linked table definitions.

Comment: The save password option does not come up. This is the problem.

Comment: So you do not see this?
http://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/cloud/linked-tables.jpg

Comment: I believe it worked! I'll test it out and then award you the bounty. By the way, do you know how to programmatically set this "save password" field through VBA? I could create the tables through VBA but I'm not sure where to find this field.

Comment: I think you would have to include it in the connection string of the linked table when creating a new TableDef, but I've never really done that.